# Leave bottom layout button hidden when adjustResize is used within a scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a layout where the main content is scrollable. At the same time the confirm button is always visible at the bottom so no matter where you are scrolling you can always confirm and see the button.

Whenever I touch a `EditText` the ScrollView scrolls up so the keyboard does not hide the `EditText`. This is done using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

The problem is, that the button always also scrolls up when I touch the EditText. I do not want this behaviour. I want the button to stay hidden behind the keyboard.

Here is the layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">


<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_second"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:hint="TYPE..."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here are two pictures demonstrating:
[image: All visible]
[image: Button shall be hidden]

On the second picture, the Button also scrolls up. But I only want the keyboard below the `EditText` the button shall stay hidden at the bottom behind the keyboard (Like it would without `adjustResize`

**EDIT:**
As suggested with FrameLayout it works when I have no content that needs to scroll. But once I add another `EditText` like below it stops working again (I am also unfamiliar with FrameLayout, I always only use ConstraintLayout, So I assume somehow the ScrollView has to stay on top of the button anyway)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">


<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_second"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:hint="TYPE..."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="TYPE..."
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="@string/previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `adjustPan`?

Comment: Why do you add extra root layouts for simple edit text and a button?
Go with FrameLayout

Comment: @Livin, I'm assuming to achieve a Floating button functionality

Comment: This is just a mwe with the default root layout. But in my real code I also use constraint layout. Just for convenience. I use it everywhere

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected?

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_item"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

layout_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:hint="TYPE..." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="previous"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes and no. It actually works, when there is no need to scroll the content, but once I add a second EditText the button pops up again. I added my new layout for test as edit to the question.